# Inconsistent height of google traffic map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I am trying to adjust the height of a google traffic map using JQuery.

This is how the map is initialized (TrafficMapController):

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 11,
        center: {lat: 50.1795159, lng: 9.040013600000066}
    });
    var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
    trafficLayer.setMap(map);
}
```

The above is executed as it is described in the documentation:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCXOgZ5cNqC4XNZIi4OjZzoMANgDnA3Tb0&callback=initMap"></script>
```

This is the adjustment of the height which is being executed after the map is loaded (DashboardController):

```
$(document).ready(function resizeGoogleMap() {
    var bodyheight = $('body').height();
    var headerHeight = $('#page-header').height();
    $('#map').css('height', bodyheight - headerHeight);
})
```

Complete Html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../frameworks/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../frameworks/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="../js/TrafficMapController.js"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCXOgZ5cNqC4XNZIi4OjZzoMANgDnA3Tb0&callback=initMap"></script>
    <script defer src="../js/DashboardController.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../frameworks/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/dashboard.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row page-header" id="page-header">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <p>Info-Dashboard</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="refresh">
                <p id="a">Aktualisierung in </p><p id="timer-count">300</p><p id="a"> Sekunden</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 info-item1">
                <div id="map"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
overflow: hidden;
}

.page-header {
    background-color: #b3b3b3;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40pt;
}

.info-item1 {
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
}

#refresh {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20pt;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    display: inline;
}

#timer-count {
    display: inline;
}

#a{
    display: inline;
    line-height: 77pt;
}
```

My problem is, that the resizing only works correctly sometimes and I am not able to figure out why.

Sometimes when the page is reloaded, the heigth of the map is correct and does fit on the page as desired, some other times the height is either too small or too big.

I would appreciate if someone could explain why this is happening.

Cheers.

Comment: Please provide some sample complete code so we can help out. I tried replicating what you gave but we can't know how your html and css are arranged with your #map div and #page-header div.

Comment: @henrisycip Thanks for trying it out! I added the code you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're trying to have the `#map` div height automatically calculate depending on the body height but keep things things in mind:

- Always set the map div's height to something. Usually it's 100% or a default would work too. `#map { height: 100% }`
- If you want to re-adjust the height when a user resizes your window, you need to place your `resizeGoogleMap()` not only on document ready, but also on a window resize event like `window.onresize = function(event)`
- If you want to resize the map height to make it responsive for mobile, just use media queries. `@media only screen and (max-width: 632px) { #map { height: 100px; } }`

The code you gave is actually still not minimal and complete. When asking questions here, always try to provide fully working code in a minimal environment. You can get rid of your other links to controllers, etc. Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zyqztdw5/3/) of some of your code in a minimal and complete example.